# How to merge two rows into one?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have the following table:

[image]

How can I merge two or more rows based on a specific column? In this case, it is column Col_4.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple groupby with agg will do the trick

```
df.groupby(['Col_1','Col_2','Col_3'],as_index = False).agg(list)
```